# MaterialUI Table Pagination doesn't update list on page change

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm trying to implement a table in my React app with MaterialUI Table. I'm using Table Pagination component and it seems that the page change handling is not working properly, the list doesn't update when changing page. What could I do?
Thanks in advance for any help. It'll be appreciated.

This is my code:

```
    const UserList = () => {
        const classes = useStyles();
        const { isLoading, error, sendRequest, clearError } = useHttpClient();
        const [usersList, setUsersList] = useState([]);
    
        useEffect(() => {
            const fetchSettings = async () => {
                try {
                    const responseData = await sendRequest(
                        process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL + '/api/users'
                    );
                    setUsersList(responseData)
                } catch (err) { }
            };
            fetchSettings();
        }, [sendRequest]);

return (
        <React.Fragment>
            <ErrorModal error={error} onClear={clearError} />
            {usersList.users ? (
                <div className={classes.root}>
                    <UsersToolbar />

                    <div className={classes.content}>
                        <UsersTable users={usersList.users} />
                    </div>
                </div>
            ) : (
                    <div>
                        {isLoading ? (
                            <label className={classes.paragraph}>Users list is loading, please wait...</label>
                        ) : (
                                <label className={classes.paragraph}>Failed to load users. Server could be offline.</label>
                            )}
                        {isLoading && <LoadingLine />}
                    </div>
                )}
        </React.Fragment>
    );
};

export default UserList;
```

...
...

```
  const UsersTable = props => {
  const { className, users, ...rest } = props;

  const classes = useStyles();

  const [selectedUsers, setSelectedUsers] = useState([]);
  const [rowsPerPage, setRowsPerPage] = useState(5);
  const [page, setPage] = useState(0);

  const handleSelectAll = event => {
    const { users } = props;

    let selectedUsers;

    if (event.target.checked) {
      selectedUsers = users.map(user => user.id);
    } else {
      selectedUsers = [];
    }

    setSelectedUsers(selectedUsers);
  };

  const handleSelectOne = (event, id) => {
    const selectedIndex = selectedUsers.indexOf(id);
    let newSelectedUsers = [];

    if (selectedIndex === -1) {
      newSelectedUsers = newSelectedUsers.concat(selectedUsers, id);
    } else if (selectedIndex === 0) {
      newSelectedUsers = newSelectedUsers.concat(selectedUsers.slice(1));
    } else if (selectedIndex === selectedUsers.length - 1) {
      newSelectedUsers = newSelectedUsers.concat(selectedUsers.slice(0, -1));
    } else if (selectedIndex > 0) {
      newSelectedUsers = newSelectedUsers.concat(
        selectedUsers.slice(0, selectedIndex),
        selectedUsers.slice(selectedIndex + 1)
      );
    }

    setSelectedUsers(newSelectedUsers);
  };

  const handlePageChange = (event, newPage) => {
    setPage(newPage);
  };

  const handleRowsPerPageChange = event => {
    setRowsPerPage(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
    <Card
      {...rest}
      className={clsx(classes.root, className)}
    >
      <CardContent className={classes.content}>
        <PerfectScrollbar>
          <div className={classes.inner}>
            <Table>
              <TableHead>
                <TableRow>
                  <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                    <Checkbox
                      style={{ color: 'orange' }}
                      checked={selectedUsers.length === users.length}
                      indeterminate={
                        selectedUsers.length > 0 &&
                        selectedUsers.length < users.length
                      }
                      onChange={handleSelectAll}
                    />
                  </TableCell>
                  <TableCell className={classes.tableCell}>Name</TableCell>
                  <TableCell className={classes.tableCell}>Email</TableCell>
                  <TableCell className={classes.tableCell}>Administrator</TableCell>
                  <TableCell className={classes.tableCell}>Registration Date</TableCell>
                </TableRow>
              </TableHead>
              <TableBody>
                {users.slice(0, rowsPerPage).map(user => (
                  <TableRow
                    className={classes.tableRow}
                    hover
                    key={user.id}
                    selected={selectedUsers.indexOf(user.id) !== -1}
                  >
                    <TableCell padding="checkbox">
                      <Checkbox
                        style={{ color: 'orange' }}
                        checked={selectedUsers.indexOf(user.id) !== -1}
                        onChange={event => handleSelectOne(event, user.id)}
                        value="true"
                      />
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell>
                      <div className={classes.nameContainer}>
                        <Avatar
                          className={classes.avatar}
                          src={user.avatarUrl}
                        >
                          {
                            (user.username)
                              .replace(/\s+/, ' ')
                              .split(' ')
                              .slice(0, 2)
                              .map(v => v && v[0].toUpperCase())
                              .join('')
                          }
                        </Avatar>
                        <Typography style={{ color: 'orange' }} variant="body1">{user.username}</Typography>
                      </div>
                    </TableCell>
                    <TableCell style={{ color: 'white' }} >{user.email}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell style={{ color: 'white' }} >{user.isAdmin.toString()}</TableCell>
                    <TableCell style={{ color: 'white' }}>
                      {moment(user.createdAt).format('YYYY-MM-DD')}
                    </TableCell>
                  </TableRow>
                ))}
              </TableBody>
            </Table>
          </div>
        </PerfectScrollbar>
      </CardContent>
      <CardActions className={classes.actions}>
        <TablePagination
          style={{ color: 'white' }}
          component="div"
          count={users.length}
          onChangePage={handlePageChange}
          onChangeRowsPerPage={handleRowsPerPageChange}
          page={page}
          rowsPerPage={rowsPerPage}
          rowsPerPageOptions={[5, 10, 25]}
        />
      </CardActions>
    </Card>
  );
};

UsersTable.propTypes = {
  className: PropTypes.string,
  users: PropTypes.array.isRequired
};

export default UsersTable;
```

Comment: You need to listen whenever the `page` state change. And when that happen, call your API to fetch the new set of `users`.

Comment: Hi @bertdida, the data is already fetched from database when component mounts. I already set the page state `const [page, setPage] = useState(0);` and use `handlePageChange()`. Can you provide an example? I didn't get your answer

Comment: Ohhh my bad. I thought you were implementing a server-side pagination.

Comment: I updated my answer to be clear

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is when you do

```js
users.slice(0, rowsPerPage).map(user => ...
```

you're looping on the same array of users, even your `page` state updates.

Change that line to

```js
users.slice(page * rowsPerPage, page * rowsPerPage + rowsPerPage).map(user => ...
```

More about `slice` function [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice).

The code above is also implemented on material-ui's table [examples](https://material-ui.com/components/tables/).

--

[image: Edit modest-dijkstra-mu5ub]

Comment: Thanks a lot @bertdida, that's the problem. Now it's working good.

Comment: Glad I could help :)